React-native google signin gives Developer Error code 10 with firebase
I used sh-1 key using ./gradlew signinReport
created and used web client
GoogleSignin.configure({ 
  offlineAccess: true,
  webClientId : "759790157334-o85m3hk9gof0p3jtdjulir4iakgufdpq.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  // offlineAccess: true,
  // hostedDomain: '',
  // loginHint: '',
  // forceConsentPrompt: true,
});

and every time I use googleSigin I get developer error with code 10
I used google cloud https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient Google cloud to create, but pasting my app package name and sh key I get already in use
I am using google-service.json provided by firebase correctly by using client id 3 and still issues not getting resolved please can any one help please please
its been 2 days I am facing same issue

I reviewed all sh-1 related answers & solutions
Sh1 related solutions
being app already created unable to use app sh and package for GCP oauth

